# var values outside the PnP JS-Core method

Tags: javascript, pnp, variable

Why doesn't this work?

**Example**

```
var w = new $pnp.Web(baseurl);
var thisfieldid;
w.lists.getByTitle("List").fields.filter("Title eq 'Column1'").get().then(function(data) {
    thisfieldid = data[0].Id;
    console.log("inside:" + thisfieldid);    
});
console.log("outside:" + thisfieldid);
```

In this Example, the variable `thisfieldid` is declared outside the pnp method, which makes it global.  When I assign a value within the method, shouldn't the value be accessible outside the method?  Instead, outside the method it is `undefined`.  Why?

(I think this might be just a javascript issue, but I'm not sure)

Comment: Can you try using it as this.thisfieldid and see if it works.

this.thisfieldid = data[0].Id;

Comment: Well, I don't see how that could help (using `this.thisfieldid` inside the method), but I tried it with the same results. If it did work, I'd have to access it outside with `w.thisfieldid` which also returns `undefined`.  It is the same without the `w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the variable is somehow not global; it's that the pnp functions are running async.  The `console.log` runs before the function finishes and so is blank.  That's why there is `.then()` to keep things running in order within the thread.

```
var w = new $pnp.Web(baseurl);
var thisfieldid;
w.lists.getByTitle("List").fields.filter("Title eq 'Column1'").get().then(function(data) {
    thisfieldid = data[0].Id;
    console.log("inside:" + thisfieldid);    
}).then(function(){;
     //now that all is finished with the function, do this:
     console.log("outside:" + thisfieldid);
});

console.log("outside:" + thisfieldid); //this fires probably before the function finishes because the function runs async
```